# How to get Gender and Age from firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am working in a project where we need to analyse the data on the basis of users gender and Age. We collect data from firebase to big query. I read some articles that firebase does not collect this data, but not completely sure.
Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Gender and age data is only shown in aggregate views in Google Analytics, and even then only when there are sufficient matches for the filter. It is also not exported to BigQuery, for the reasons shown in this [documentation page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en#thresholds):

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from **inferring the demographics or interests of individual users**. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a report, then data for the male value may be withheld.

If you need user-level precision for gender/age, consider asking your users for that data, and explaining how you will use it.